# How to set received Browserpush notification in browser to wait for 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push

I am using firebase cloud messaging library for sending notification.
Is there any way in service worker js to mentione n seconds so that received browser push notification should wait for n seconds and then disappear.

I have gone through https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
But didn't found my solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably you just want to set the `requireInteraction` option to `false`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification

Comment: @collimarco thanks for the quick reply . But is there any way to set this time by ourself. I mean to say 10 secs,15 secs like that?